# How to create a horizontal ul list in css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

how do I create a navigation bar in html / css with a horizontal alignment while using CSS GRID?

I can't get the text to get in line, it stacks above each other no matter what I do.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. By default, CSS doesn't have a grid system. Grid systems are a common tools that frameworks, like Twitter's Bootstrap, will implement for faster and more efficient development. It's too difficult to know what you want based on your question.  I urge you to read **all** of the links in my next post.

Comment: [Please, do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: Try using bootstrap

Comment: Just use the *grid-template-columns* wisely. CSS GRID is a two-dimensional feature.

Comment: I'd say Harish's answer is correct for your question, but I don't think CSS Grid is the right tool for the job. If you need only a single line of list items, I'd use `display: flex`.

Comment: @adprocas: CSS *does* have a [grid system](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/). There's no conceivable reason to pull in frameworks like Bootstrap and infest your HTML documents with formatting hints via classes or otherwise. [CSS Grid Changes EVERYTHING](https://youtu.be/7kVeCqQCxlk). This question is asking how to lay out a menu horizontally across a grid track. It's not asking how to use CSS Grid Layout to create a menu, as Vince seems to imply.

Comment: @IInspectable, I stand corrected. I don't do much CSS anymore, but CSS Grid does look appealing. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 11):

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Contact us</li>
    <li>Report</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

A simplest example of navigation bar using **CSS GRID**

Comment: That works, but why? hm..

Comment: In the above code, you can see I have divided the screen space into 5 equal fractions. [**grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;**]. Now

Comment: Now, whenever you add an *<li>* item, each of the *<li>* item will be distributed to each column. If you have 10 *<li>* items, then you will have 2 rows with 5 columns. Just try adding more *<li>* items to get more understanding of it. **CSS GRID** is more effective when you design a 2-dimensional structure. Similarly, **CSS FLEX** is more effective for 1-dimensional as @Vince said!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that instead of ```1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr``` you can use ```repeat(5, 1fr)```